# Is there a way to set up "loading: lazy" instead of default "loading: eager" for all inline images in gatsby-source-wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading, gatsby

I'm trying to decrease page loading time. Right now all images which came from Wordpress content are geting "loading: eager". In result all images are downloading immediately all together on the page. So I would like to know is there an option to set up by default "loading: lazy" for all images which come from content of gatsby-source-wordpress.

To show images I'm just using this way:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
```

Gatsby v3.14,
NodeJs 12.22.6,
Gatsby-source-wordpress 5.14,
Gatsby-plugin-image 1.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best chance is customizing the `content` that is rendering the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or trying [`gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images/)

For the first approach, a library such as `html-react-parser` may fit your requirements.

Instead of:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHtml={{__html: content}}/>
```

You will do:

```
<div>{parse(content, {replace: replaceMedia})}</div>
```

Where `replaceMedia` is a function that gets the nodes and replaces them by a custom markup:

```
const replaceMedia = node => {
  if (node.name === 'img') {
    console.log("Check the node data:", node)
    return <img src={node.attribs.src} loading="lazy" alt="Some alternative text" />
  }
};
```

Test it to check the data inside `node` and tweak it accordingly. If your images are locally set, you can even use a custom component to return a `GatsbyImage`.

The second approach will rely on your set up, which has not been provided in the question.

Useful resources:

- https://dimitr.im/optimize-loading-images-wordpress-gatsby
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images/

Comment: I've tried your approach with html-react-parser and it works well for me. Another ways that you mantioned (gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images and from dimitr.io) seems like already have been depricated and not compatible since Gatsby version 3. But  i'm still a little puzzled because there's no option in gatsby-config.js to allow us to set loading by default as lazy...